# Select specific columns in adonis JS using ORM

Tags: node.js, orm, adonis.js

There is a way in Adonis JS using

```
Database.select('name','email').from('users')
```

Is there a way to achieve this using ORM?

```
const User = use('App/Models/User')

//wherever required

let users = User.find(key).fetch({'name', email'})
```

Something similar to what we use in Laravel.

`User::find(1)->pluck('name');` or `User::find(1)->get(['name']);`

Answer (score 2):

The static method **find** in model returns this

`return yield this.query().where(key, value).first()`

so you can edit your query to this

```
yield User.query().where('id', key).select('name', 'email').first()
```

It will be the same that you are trying to do

Comment: use **await** in case you are using adonis 4.0 or greater

Answer (score 1):

Adonis has also some [helper methods](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/query-builder#_helpers) for the query builder which are described in the docs like `pluck`. So to get the result you would have something like:

```
const result = await Database.from('users')
  .where('id', 1)
  .pluck('name');

return result;
```

Or another approach

```
const result = await User.query()
  .where('id', 1)
  .pluck('name')
  .first();

return result;
```